# What is the difference between c-find and c-get DIMSE?

Tags: dicom

All . Forgive me just a newbie in the DICOM. And was reading the DIMSE part of the DICOM standard. Found both c-find and c-get have the query/retrieve functionality against DICOM PACS server.

So I tried to summary the difference between them.

1. C-get will trigger one or more c-store operation between SCU and SCP.
2. C-get is the query for the image. But c-find is just the query for the attributes except the image.
3. C-find would return multiple response messages if there exist multiple DICOM for the query criteria.

Please help to review my understanding. Correct me if there is any error.  Thanks.

Comment: There is a nice, recent post by David Clunie about C-GET vs. C-MOVE: http://dclunie.blogspot.be/2016/05/to-c-move-is-human-to-c-get-divine.html

Comment: Thank you guys, @LEADTOOLSSupport Why not post your comments as an answer.   and Tisys The link you share to me it is really worth to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use C-Find command for query and C-GET command for retrieval of DICOM storage instances (images, reports etc.). C-Get is performed in the single association (connection) but not commonly used. Instead, C-Move is used for retrieval of DICOM storage instances and which uses a different association (connection) and role reversal (SCP acts as SCU) to send the data to destination (caller or another SCP/Server)